# Want compare time in bash and python within the same python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, time

Gday all,

well Im trying to do the next:

I have a RSA cipher implemented by myself (it works quite well), not using any libraries. my question is, how can I execute bash time from within my python script and compare with python time and have both results into a text file?

so far I got this script:

```
import os
import struct, types, sys, timeit
from time import time
sys.stdout = open("/home/spike/salida_pruebas.txt", "w")
print "I will call this rsa.py"
orsa1 = time()
os.system("python rsa.py")
orsa2 = time()
orsa = orsa2 - orsa1
bashCommand = "time python rsa.py >> /home/spike/tiempos_prueba.txt"
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()
print output
print "RSA (other algorithm implementarion) encryption is in %f seconds" % (orsa)
```

but when I run this script I dont get the time output, I get the rsa.py output which is no good for me.

Thanks a lot.

----- Update (20/7/14 12:35 GMT -4) ----

Question update:

OK, the first question has been answered and works great, but I have an update regarding it.

Now I want to add a bash for loop in my python script, my bash for loop works fine in the shell but doesnt work in my python script:

```
import os
import struct, types, sys, timeit
from time import time
sys.stdout = open("/home/spike/salida_pruebas_10.txt", "w")
print "First we will run blockciphers, many of the AES finalists"
print "I will call this other program called blowfish.py and test its time"

b1 = time()
for x in range(0, 10):
    os.system("python blowfish.py")
b2 = time()
b = b2 - b1
print "blowfish encryption is in %f seconds in %d iterations" % (b, x+1)
os.system("{ time bash -c 'for i in {1..10}; do python blowfish.py; done' }  2>> /home/spike/salida_pruebas_10.txt")
```

My final goal is to compare my time (calculated in python, quiet simple) and linux time (user, real, sys time)  in 10 iterations just as an example, because I need to do it for 100K iterations.

So this is the problem:

```
time bash -c 'for i in {1..10}; do python blowfish.py; done'
```

works great in shell, but i get this error when I called it in my python script (above):

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "do" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

Again thanks a lot.

---- Update (20/7/14 18:15 GMT -4) -----

Found the error, I forgot to add semicolon (;) at the end of the for loop line:

```
os.system("{ time bash -c 'for i in {1..10}; do python aes.py; done' ; }  2>> /home/spike/salida_pruebas_10bash.txt")
```

hope all of this helps to someone else.

Cheers

Comment: Use the ``timeit`` module.

Comment: Thanks, 

I really want to have at least the user+sys time from bash, i want to compare the bash result with the python result all in a python script.

Comment: I think you should add "shell=True" when calling subprocess.Popen, since redirecting is a function from the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From bash:

```
{ time python rsa.py ; }  2>  /home/spike/tiempos_prueba.txt
```

**Curly brackets** are necessary, otherwise time will be also measured for the redirect.

**2>** is to redirect only stderr (in case your script produces some output), since time writes its output to stderr.

From python script:

```
import os
os.system("{ time python rsa.py ; }  2>  /home/spike/tiempos_prueba.txt")
```